# Angular Material - How to create floating card + toolbar layout

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How can i create a toolbar with floating toolbar and card layout as shown in the image below.

[image: https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_12/assets/0Bx4BSt6jniD7bW1TYXlMT0JxUWM/layout-structure-toolbars4.png]

This was taken from official material website.

```
<div id="profile-edit">
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <span>Outer Toolbar</span>

    <mat-toolbar-row>
    </mat-toolbar-row>

    <mat-toolbar-row>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
  <mat-card class="example-card">
    <mat-toolbar>
      <span>Inner Card Toolbar</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

This is what is what i have so far i created 1 outer toolbar with 2 rows to add height.

I don't know how to float the card centre of the page and center of the toolbar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the header, try this

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
  <mat-toolbar-row></mat-toolbar-row>
  <mat-toolbar-row></mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

For the card,

```
<mat-card class="card">
  <mat-card-header class="header">
    <div class="subheading-2 title">Title</div>
    <div class="header-actions">
      <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>search</mat-icon></button>
      <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>view_module</mat-icon></button>
      <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>more_vertical</mat-icon></button>
    </div>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content class="content">
    <!-- Insert content here -->
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

And finally, add these styles

```
$header-height: 64px;

.card {
  padding: 0;
  margin: -$header-height auto 0;
  width: 75%;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: $header-height;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);

  .title {
    margin-right: auto;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
}

.content {
  height: 400px;
}
```

[STACKBLITZ EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-beta12-9yi7fj)

Comment: Ok... Obviously without more details or a reproduction, I can't really help.

Comment: It shows like H1 then I change it to a simple <span> and now it looks nice ! thanks.